# Why is 96.74-60 equal to 36.739999999999995 in JS?

Tags: javascript

Shouldn't it be 36.74? Can someone explain what goes on behind the scenes & why does it make sense (if any) for such calculations?

```js
console.log(96.74 - 60)
```

Comment: TLDR: Those calculations are very fast, floating points are shorter than their precise equivalent, and the results are accurate enough for most things. In your case its 0.0000000000005 off, I mean, no one cares right?